# How to make display PDF images with mouse hover in iTerm2 after " ls -l '?

Tags: macos, pdf, mouse, iterm

On Catalina 10.15.2, Sometimes, in iTerm2 terminal, after a `ls -l` command, I can visualize some pdf files (a popup window appears suddenly) when my mouse is over the list of PDF filenames.

But this is not systematically and I would like to know how to make appear this popup window into which the image of filename pointed appears (that would be very useful because this popup window is relatively large and we can distinguish details).

If someone could know what to do to activate systematically this behavior with mouse (maybe it is a shortcut with mouse or other things, I don't know), this would be nice to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate this behavior in iTerm2 by activating the "Look up & data detectors multitouch shortcut. On Force Touch trackpads, by default, that means a force press by default while the cursor is placed over the filename.

You can confirm your settings in System Preferences, by viewing the Trackpad pane.

You may also wish to hold CMD and click on the filename to open it directly.